# Default menu assignment for a new module

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, administrator

While creating a new module, is it possible to change the default menu assignment from 'All pages' to 'no pages'? I haven't be able to find anything that would allow that switch in the global configuration, and the default being set to 'All pages' has been causing us some problems.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Advanced Module Manager by nonumber allows this

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/advancedmodulemanager

I do not know if the free version includes it but I would assume it would, in the Options for the advanced module manager you will see a settings for Default Menu Assignment.

There are also many MANY more features with it that extend the native module manager to the extreme. Worthwhile on pretty much any Joomla site.

Comment: I actually had thought of this too, but I checked an older version of Nonumber and thought it couldn't be done. But it looks like Jordan's right - in the most recent version, Peter has added this function. Once you have it installed, click module, options, then in default settings you can select default menu assignment to none.

Comment: Credit goes to Jordan!